# Unique elements in matrix

Tags: list, matrix, prolog

I have a matrix, where every element should be unique. To be honest, every element can take an integer value in [1, 19], but I got confused on handling list with variables with `length(List, 3)`, so for now I have this:

```
matrix([[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]).

row(M, N, Row) :-
    nth1(N, M, Row).

column(M, N, Col) :-
    transpose(M, MT),
    row(MT, N, Col).

get_row(N, Row) :-
    matrix(M),
    row(M, N, Row).

diff_matrix(M) :-
    matrix(M),
    foo(M).

foo([]).
foo([H|T]) :-
    length(H, Len),
    write(Len),
    foo(T).

different_from([], _).
different_from([H|T], E) :- 
    E \= H, 
    different_from(T, E).
```

Any idea to proceed with this code, or maybe another approach? I mean if my attempt is not good enough, I do not have problem replacing it.

---

*EDIT*:

1. I have atoms, because I do not know how to constraint variables
   inside [1, 19], so I am trying to make it work with atoms, for now!
2. I want my code to test if matrix contains unique elements, i.e., for
   every element found in the matrix, there is no duplicate element in
   the matrix.
3. So far, I have only predicates that should help, nothing more, since
   I am stuck.

A possible query: `diff_matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]).`

Comment: You said the elements can take on values in the range `1` to `19`. But your `matrix` fact has atoms `a` through `g` as values. Atoms are not variables, so can you explain? And what do you want your code to do? Is it supposed to be true if a given matrix has all unique elements? This isn't clear.

Comment: @lurker I was testing here http://swish.swi-prolog.org/, and now I closed it so all my queries are gone (it doesn't seem to remember them). What I was hoping to do, was to create a query that would ask Prolog to check if matrix has unique elements or not. Yeah that's right. I only have the matrixs with atoms, because my final goal is to have a matrix with variables, that are going to be constrained..

Comment: You can remove the fact `matrix([[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]).`. It serves no purpose. I assume you'd just want to call, for example, `diff_matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]).` and you'd want it to come back "true".

Comment: Maybe you didn't see my edit in the comment, so yes @lurker!

Comment: I saw the edit, but it didn't say specifically what your query was to be. It needs to be made clear.

Comment: cheating: `?- matrix(M),flatten(M,F),sort(F,S),length(F,L),length(S,L).`

Comment: @CapelliC it's not cheating if it meets the requirement in this case (+1).

Comment: @CapelliC why cheating? I mean your answer differs by your comment, but both seem logical, I am now looking for an online platform to test, since the one I linked to, seems to throw a 502...I didn't know that what I was trying did so much harm :/

Comment: @gsamaras: is kind of very inflexible, based on a specific behaviour (sort/2 removed duplicates), so you have no control about the test performed on each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very compact, maybe inefficient, method based on indexing

```
rc(M,R,C,E) :- nth1(R,M,Row),nth1(C,Row,E).

diff_matrix(M) :-
  forall((rc(M,I,J,X),rc(M,U,V,Y)), ((I\=U;J\=V)->X\=Y;true)).
```

*edit*

rc/4 is the relation among matrix M, row index R (1 based), column index C, and element E.

[forall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2)(Cond,Action) documentation states:

> For all alternative bindings of Cond, Action can be proven.

So we can read diff_matrix/1 as

for all elements X (let's say, M[I,J]) and Y (M[U,V]) either I=U and J=V or X \= Y (doesn't unify)

Comment: usage: `?- diff_matrix([[1,2],[3,4]]).`